# PS3 copy video files from BD-R to HDD

Tags: ps3

I have been using a Blu-ray DVR to record some items. The BD-R plays fine on the PS3, but I would like to copy the video files (already mp4) to the PS3's HDD. Pressing <kbd>△</kbd> on the disc or video file doesn't give me the option to copy or move.

Am I correct in assuming that the files cannot be copied?

Comment: You own the copyright to content on these disks?

Comment: sure, there is no DRM on the items.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to directly rip movies to the PS3, as there's no onboard encoder, (except for specific games, like Just Cause 2 or Uncharted 3). Your best bet is to rip via PC and copy

Comment: I don't need to rip the disc. The files are already mp4. So want to copy just like you can with a USB stick.